# Repeating sections auto numbering

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way you can make it an option to have the auto numbering turned off on repeating sections?

It's causing a lot of errors with the staff that are reviewing the forms.  For instance, by default I think it says "Item 1, Item 2, etc".  In my form I have to insert a "Zone 1, Zone 2, etc."  However I might jump right from Zone 2 to Zone 95, but your form shows up as Item 3.  So our staff might input it as Zone 3 instead of Zone 95.  It's been a big headache to try to get them to understand this.  Just wondering if the auto numbering can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are embedding your forms in your own website, you can use CSS to target the repeating section title elements and either modify the text to be blank, just "Zone", etc.  The CSS class for the repeating section titles is `c-repeating-section-item-title`.

This would hide the repeating section titles:

`.c-repeating-section-item-title H4 { display: none; }`